# Change datatype on scala Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

On that course on Module 3 - hands on lab ... there's an example (Spark Fundamentals 1) that I'm using to learn Scala and Spark.

https://courses.cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:BigDataUniversity+BD0211EN+2016/courseware/14ec4166bc9b4a3a9592b7960f4a5401/b0c736193c834b01b3c1c5bd4ce2d8a8/

I tried to modify the Streaming part in order to calculate the moving average as streaming comes in. I haven't figured out how to do it, but right now I'm facing the problem that I don't know how to change the datatype.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(1))

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",7777)

import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
var ints = Queue[Double]()

def movingAverage(values: Queue[Double], period: Int): List[Double] = {
   val first = (values take period).sum / period
   val subtract = values map (_ / period)
   val add = subtract drop period
   val addAndSubtract = add zip subtract map Function.tupled(_ - _)
   val res = (addAndSubtract.foldLeft(first :: List.fill(period - 1)(0.0)) { 
     (acc, add) => (add + acc.head) :: acc 
   }).reverse
   res
 }

val pass = lines.map(_.split(",")).
    map(pass=>(pass(7).toDouble))

pass.getClass
```

> class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream

```
ints ++= List(pass).to[Queue]
```

> Name: Compile Error
>
> Message: console :41: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : scala.collection.mutable.Queue[org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Double]]
>
> required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[Double]
>
> ```
>           ints ++= List(pass).to[Queue]
>                                 ^
> ```
>
> StackTrace:

```
al pass2 = movingAverage(ints,2)

pass2.print()
ints.dequeue

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

How to get the streaming data from pass to ints as a queue of doubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of asking

```
val p1 = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Double]

pass.foreachRDD( rdd => {
    for(item <- rdd.collect().toArray) {
        p1 += item ;  
        println(item +" - "+ movingAverage(p1,2).last) ;
    }    
})
```